# Making Images a Constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I have a a const color variable `const color = ["red", "green", "blue"];`. Instead of colors, I would like to have images. I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Below, I have included how I tried to do this, which didn't work. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to do this. Thank you!

```
import C1 from '../carousel-images/carousel-1.jpg';
import C2 from '../carousel-images/carousel-2.jpg';
import C3 from '../carousel-images/carousel-3.jpg';

const image = ["C1", "C2", "C3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of strings instead of images. Try remove the quotes from the array values

```js
images = [C1, C2, C3]
```